# unable to set location for winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried/researched for an entire day to set the location of Form2 called by a button click on Form1.
I allow the user to resize the forms and want Form2 to open at the same size and location of Form1 (wherever it is when they click the button).
This is what I've tried so far:`

```
            app.hnow = this.Height;// size of form displayed now
            app.wnow = this.Width;
            app.module = 2; //indicates look up mode              
            lookprmtby lookby = new lookprmtby(this); instantiate Form2
            app.hprev = lookby.ClientSize.Height; // gets original size of form being called
            app.wprev = lookby.ClientSize.Width;
            lookby.ClientSize = new Size(app.wnow, app.hnow);// set new size before show  
            lookby.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            lookby.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            // set lookby's location to same location as current form - i.e. left = 0 top = 174
            lookby.Location = this.Location;// this does not work / lookby.location is 0,0 after this statement
            lookby.Left = this.Location.X; // left and top do not work either-they evaluate to 0
            lookby.Top = this.Location.Y;
            lookby.Show();`
```

FYI, ClientSize is equivilent to the Size property. I'm using BinaryMission's ModernChromeWindow style as the basis for the majority of my forms.

Can anyone see the reason why the lookby.location property is evaluating to 0,0?

(VS 2019, c#)

Comment: `otherForm.Bounds = this.Bounds;`

Comment: @Jimi that doesn't work either.